# How to use an image style in a Drupal 8 twig template?

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

I am trying to print an image using an image style that I've created in my drupal 8 theme.

I can print an image in a template by doing {{ content.banner }} but how do I apply the image style to that image? I tried looking for documentation but there doesn't seem to be any out there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Currently drupal 8 doesn't have special filter for applying image style. Instead you can set new attribute for your image like this:

```
{% set image = image|merge({'#image_style': 'thumbnail'}) %}
```

Then simply output your updated image:

```
{{ image }}
```

P.S . You can do `{{ dump(image) }}` to see what  attributes you can update

Comment: I also actually found in the content type settings, you can display all images for that content type to be of Image Style X. So I could do it from my answer or yours, but yours is better imo.

Comment: What variable should I use for "image" ? 
content.field_bloc_1_image.entity does not works for example :s

Comment: I could not get this to work. It does not use the image style? I have {% set image = content.field_global_image|merge({'#image_style': 'thumbnail'}) %}
{{ image }}

Comment: I am using a media bundle for my image and rendering it in a node display of teaser.  This code worked for me to apply the image style to the field named field_teaser_image: 

{# set image style #}
{% set img = content.field_teaser_image.0|merge({ '#image_style' : 'thumbnail'}) %}

{# render image #}
{{ img }}

Thanks pavlovich / Megan!

Answer (score 5):

I resolve this by creating my own **Twig Filter**.

You can do the same by creating your own module exposing this **Filter**.

Feel free to re-use it.

**Code**

```
namespace Drupal\twig_extender\TwigExtension;

use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\Core\Link;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

use Drupal\file\Entity\File;
use Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle;

class Images extends \Twig_Extension {
     /**
     * Generates a list of all Twig functions that this extension defines.
     */
     public function getFunctions(){
         return array(
             new \Twig_SimpleFunction('image_style', array($this, 'imageStyle'), array('is_safe' => array('html'))),
         );
     }

    /**
    * Gets a unique identifier for this Twig extension.
    */
    public function getName() {
        return 'twig_extender.twig.images';
    }


     /**
      * Generate images styles for given image
      */
      public static function imageStyle($file_id, $styles) {
          $file = File::load($file_id);
          $transform = array();
          if (isset($file->uri->value)) {
              $transform['source'] = $file->url();
              foreach ($styles as $style) {
                  $transform[$style] = ImageStyle::load($style)->buildUrl($file->uri->value);
              }
          }
         return $transform;
      }
}
```

**Usage**

```
{% set transform = image_style(image.entity.fid.value, ['thumbnail', 'large']) %}
```

Then you have access to the source image & styles

```
{{ transform.source }}
{{ transform.thumbnail }}
{{ transform.large }}
```

Hope it will help you guy !

Comment: I tried above method. I put the above code in `/modules/custom_module/src/TwigExtension/Images.php` But still getting error `Twig_Error_Syntax: Unknown "image_style" function. in Twig_ExpressionParser->..`

Comment: From now I'm using Bamboo Twig (Drupal 8 module). Which expose, in the Bamboo Twig Loader extension, 2 twig functions to render images. Here the doc of Bamboo Twig: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/bamboo-twig/usage. The functions are `bamboo_render_image` & `bamboo_render_image_style`.

Comment: One of our Drupal projects is using this code snippet. It throws an error after upgrading to Drupal 9. "Call to a member function buildUri() on null". Anyone run into this?

Answer (score 4):

How to do this without contrib module: make it your own render array.

```
{% for item in content.field_images['#items'] %}
  {% set image = {
    '#theme':      'image_style',
    '#style_name': 'medium',
    '#uri':        item.entity.uri.value,
    '#alt':        item.alt,
    '#width':      item.width,
    '#height':     item.height
  } %}
  {{ image }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably worth mentioning, that it's useful to first question your assumption.  Do you really need to do this in Twig?  If you can just configure a view-mode (or Views field) to render the image field with the appropriate (responsive) image style, that would be much simpler.